# Has Ashton Kutcher retired from acting?

Tags: acting-career

Of lately, the actor Ashton Kutcher has not done any movies. He was offered the role of product engineer at Lenovo. Has he taken this career as his full time job and retired from acting?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't know whether Ashton Kutcher still works at Lenovo, or how much time he devotes to that job, but he has been starring in Netflix show *[The Ranch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ranch_(TV_series))* since 2016. His filmography certainly suggests he's no longer as active as he once was, but he does not appear to have retired from acting completely.